# How to write fql query for images of specific album

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-fql

I need to retrieve src_small images.

```
NSString *query=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT pid,src_small,src_big FROM photo WHERE aid IN ( SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=%@)",ownerId];
```

I wrote this query, and this works fine. But it gives me data of all the albums.

What i want is to retrieve images for specific album only, not for all the albums.

How should i reframe my query to solve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Its FQL. Facebook Querry Language.

Comment: Ok, I thought its SQL looking at SELECT FROM ..

Comment: @nikita *yes you do* -- even anonymous users can submit suggested edits! Just click 'edit' link.. don't hesitate to do so!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

obviously:

```
NSString *query = [NSString stringWithFormat : @"SELECT pid, src_small, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = '%@'", aId];
```

hope this helps

Comment: I need to provide owner id also.